# New map file with LaTeX

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I'm trying to use the `textgreek` package to typeset a sigma (σ) in a Roman/upright face. Unfortunately, I need to include trees drawn with the `xyling` package, which requires me to typeset with the `latex` rendering enging (as opposed to `pdflatex`) and, in the past, I have always included `\pdfmapfile{=cbgreek-full.map}` in my preamble, for, without this, the document will not render, with `pdflatex` I get:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 grmn1200
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for grmn1200.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file grmn1200): Font grmn1200 at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

And, when I use `dvipdf` on the `.dvi` file produced by `latex` I get:

```
dvips: Font grmn1200 not found,  using cmr10 instead.
dvips: Design size mismatch in font grmn1200
dvips: Checksum mismatch in font grmn1200
```

So, is there an equivalent of `\pdfmapfile{=cbgreek-full.map}` which I can use with `latex`, for attempting to use this with `latex` gives:

```
! pdfTeX error (\pdfmapfile): not allowed in DVI mode (\pdfoutput <= 0).
<recently read> \pdfmapfile 

l.27 \pdfmapfile
                {=cbgreek-full.map}
No pages of output.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{xyling}
\usepackage{textgreek}
%\pdfmapfile{=cbgreek-full.map}

\begin{document}

  In producing these syllabifications, I was working within the formalism
  of \textit{government phonology} and with government phonology comes a 
  number of axioms within which we must work. This framework includes a 
  number of significant revisions on the ``traditional'' syllabification.
  The most obvious is the loss of the \textsigma

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess you have to load the map file in the `dvips` step, rather than in the `latex` step. But why not installing the `cbgreek` font package?

Comment: Okay, thanks, how exactly can I do that, do you know? Also, I have the package installed, let me see if loading helps.

Comment: The fonts are sitting there in my `texmf` directory. As far as I know they're installed correctly, I'm not sure why `latex` and `pdflatex` are having trouble accessing them without the `\pdfmapfile` command. In that directory, by the way, is where `cbgreek-full.map` is located

Comment: How did you install the fonts? That map is part of TeX Live so I'm guessing you are not using TeX Live. If you installed them yourself in your personal or local texmf tree, where did you put the map file exactly and did you run updmap or updmap-sys to install the fonts correctly?

Comment: I didn't, no. I have now re-checked my installation and made sure all of the fonts are in the right place. In the first instance I hadn't followed the manual correctly, but everything's fixed now. Thank you all :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to a bad installation (solved doing it correctly)